# Composer is using the wrong version of php on Mac Sierra

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I get this error when I run composer update:
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7 but your PHP version (5.6.30) does not satisfy that requirement.

When I run php -v I get:

```
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: May  6 2017 10:02:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in your composer.json :

```
"config": {
   "platform": {
       "php": "7.1"
   }
}
```